# Access return value

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have this function:

```
functionName :: notimportant => a -> ([a])
```

I would like to recursively call this function and at each call to modify/update the return (the 2 elements from the tuple). The problem is that I do not know how to pattern match the tuple in order to add at each function's call elements in the list(the first parameter of the returned tuple).

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, but `let` can certainly pattern match a tuple: `let (something, function) = functionName ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't understood your question. If it becomes more coherent, so may this answer.

The canonical code that applies a function like yours recursively is the following:

```
data Tree a = Node a [a]

unfold :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> Tree a
unfold f x = Node x $ map (unfold f) $ f x
```

You talk of tuples. I see no tuple in your type signature.

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. The idea is that I need to call the function recursively and among the way add the `Something par1 par2` parameters into the list of `Something par1 par2`, which is returned by the function. I edited my question.